# Search Bar has wider frame at viewDidLoad

Tags: ios8, frame, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I created `UISearchController` programmatically and I had set frame for searchBar that I added in it. But the `searchBar` has `wider frame` and once I tap on it and tap on the `cancel` button with search bar; it regains the correct frame. How to set it correct at `viewDidLoad`?

Code is as such:

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44)];
searchControllerMain = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.searchResultController];
searchControllerMain.searchBar.delegate = self;
searchControllerMain.searchResultsUpdater = self;
[searchControllerMain.searchBar sizeToFit];
[searchControllerMain.searchBar setPlaceholder:@"events"];
searchControllerMain.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
searchControllerMain.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[self.searchResultController.tableView reloadData];

UIView *searchBarContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];
[searchBarContainer addSubview:searchControllerMain.searchBar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarContainer];
```

Comment: Could you post your code please? Without it, it's difficult to know what you're doing wrong and it also avoid questions like: "Are you setting frame size correctly?" etc ...

Comment: Can you just replace `searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44)];` with `searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];` and check if it fixes your issue?

Comment: Did that too. Also gave frame to `searchBarContainer` but both approaches didn't work!

Comment: you should set the frame for `searchControllerMain.searchBar` and not just `searchBar`. `UISearchController` creates the search bar for you, you don't need to alloc it yourself.

Comment: `searchControllerMain.searchBar` is a readonly property..I can't set a frame for it. Also if I don't set frame for `searchBar` and use the default searchBar from `searchControllerMain.searchBar` it widened its frame to the left corner now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I place a `searchBar` in the navigation item's `titleView`.

```
self.searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
self.searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search gospel events";
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;
```

As you can see, I don't set a frame.  It starts off with the right initial size, and will adjust sizes as orientation changes.

Have you tried setting an explicit `autoresizingMask`?  I've never tried placing it in a custom bar button item, so I'm not sure if that will also fix your custom container issue.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...I have tried giving autoResizingMask for the searchBar but that too was of no significance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   [searchControllerMain.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44)];
   [searchControllerMain.searchBar setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44)];
}
```

It worked for me!!